# Cannot get a popup to work in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am sure I am just missing something basic, but can anyone see anything wrong with the following code?  When I click the first button, it does not open a popup.  The second button opens the popup as a dialog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- JQUERY MOBILE CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//codeorigin.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="//codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>                                 
    <!-- JQUERY MOBILE -->
    <script src="//codeorigin.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="content">
            <p><a href="#menu-items" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true">Open Popup</a></p>
            <p><a href="#menu-items" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Open Popup(dialog)</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-items" data-role="popup">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed it's a small thing you're missing! =)

[**jQuery 1.3 Mobile Pop-up Docs**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/):

> ...then create a link with the href set to the id of the popup div, and add the attribute data-rel="popup" to tell the framework to open the popup when the link is tapped. This is a similar markup pattern to the dialog widget. **A popup div has to be nested inside the same page as the link.**

Move the `<div id="menu-items"></div>` to within the `<div id="home" data-role="page"><div>` node, then that should be it!

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CV6A8/) included. [*Dialogs*](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/) are deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0.

Answer (score 3):

i think there are two things:

```
 I). for opening a popup you have to place popup content inside the data-role='page' 

 II). for opening a dialog you have to place dialog content outside the data-role='page'
```

working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/10/